# Asynchronous loading of form in bootstrap modal from external script

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, asynchronous

I have an issue loading a form in a bootstrap modal. I am using a service called Formstack to embed a form into my website. The embed code provided to me uses an external script to load the proper CSS, HTML, and JS into my page. The problem is that I am getting 10K+ warnings in my browser console once the page is loaded. All the warnings are the same. Each warning reads:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Here is a link to that javascript file: https://trustdale.formstack.com/forms/js.php/business_contact

Looking at the external javascript, EVERY line begins with **document.write**. I dont know if it matters, but I am loading the form in a bootstrap modal. Also note that the form loads totally fine... unless I'm missing something. How would I load my form without all the warnings?

Comment: FYI: I've researched this for the past day... and I couldnt find anything related to this question because of the fact that I am loading an external script that I cant modify, since it is generated dynamically.

Comment: "How would I load my form without all the warnings?" — You'd have to change the script … which you can't because it is a third party supplied and hosted one.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... I dont quite understand it yet, but I stumbled upon this https://github.com/krux/postscribe, which seems to make my code work. I created an empty div in my modal with an id of #formCode, then placed this section of code in my footer:

```
<script>
      $( function(){
          postscribe('#formCode', '<script src={!! $contact_form !!}><\/script>');
      });
</script>
```

$contact_form only contains the value of my script "src" attribute.

Again, dont know how it works, just does. Maybe someone could elaborate